# CentOS7にgcc-c++の4.6を入れようとしても4.8になる

Tags: centos

http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4865940227
上記の書籍で紹介されていたディープラーニング
ツールのOSSである「Caffe」導入で、
g++-4.6が必要だと紹介されていた。
書籍ではapt-get系の導入が紹介されていたため、
自分の利用マシンであるCentOS7に読み替えて導入を試みた。

> yum remove gcc*
>   yum update

などした後に
https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gcc-c%2B%2B
から落とした4.6系rpmをlocalinstallするが、
バージョンを確認すると4.8が入ってしまう。
（ログは今手元に無いので、後ほどアップする）

確かめたいこと

- 特定のバージョンに絞ったインストールはrpmがあっても不可能なのか？

Comment: 質問には直接関係ないですが、新しいバージョンである４．８では問題があるのですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

リンク先には CentOS 7 用の gcc-c++-4.6 が無いようです。
noarch ではない、x86_64, i*86 の RPM の場合、それぞれの OS の環境(ライブラリなど)でコンパイルされたものですので、違う OS (今回の CentOS 7) にはインストールできない場合が多いです。

「g++-4.6が必要」とは「g++ バージョン 4.6 以降が必要」ということではないでしょうか？
どうしてもバージョン 4.6 が必要なのであれば、fedora 15, 16 あたりから gcc-4.6.*.src.rpm を持ってきて CentOS 7 環境でビルドすれば、インストールできるかもしれません。